# how to bold equation in lyx

Tags: equations, lyx, bold, elsarticle

I have equations inside text.

I tried to bold equation from lyx text style->series bold
but only text is bolded but equations are not.

I can make font larger for equation and other options but bold and italic is not working for equations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the specific font options for math mode. Select the text in the math mode box and use this button on the math toolbar:

[image]